# Pass data from popup window to parent window not working with Javascript in master page in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net, master-pages

I am opening a modal window on click on a button from a page(ABC.aspx). Code is follows

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "ffff","myFunction();", true);
}
```

This method is calling a javascript function `myFunction()`. This javascript code is present in `Site.master` file. Code is as follows

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function myFunction() {
        var myWindow = 
            window.showModalDialog("XYModalWindow.aspx", object, "width=100, height=50");
    }

    </script>
    <link href="~/SomeStyleSheet.css" type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
```

This javascript code is opening a pop-up window where I am saving a few records in the database.

**Goal:** After saving the data into the database from the popup window, I have to populate it in the parent window (i.e. ABS.aspx).

**Issue:** As my javascript is present in master page I am not able to pass data to the parent page from popup window the way it has been mentioned on several pages on the internet.

I tried saving data in session variable in popup window and access in parent window but this doesn't seems to work.

Note: I want to fetch data in parent window automatically without using any extra event. I mean popup window data saved and window is closed then it should automatically display that data in parent window (no extra button click).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it looks liek you have a server-side button that calls client-side code.  Is this necessary?  Why not save to the database using a web service and then updating display on page in your onSuccess callback function?  Wouldn't require a postback and you won't have to worry about calling client-side code from code-behind event handlers.

Try creating a  with the fields you need in your popup.  Set it's style to "display:none".  So you'll have a hidden field with a button and a textbox, for example.

Then, create an event handler to display that div - so when someone clicks a certain button, turn that div into a dialog box with jQuery and display it.  Then, when someone clicks the button INSIDE the dialog box, you can call the web service to update database and then update page accordingly (if success do X, if failure do Y, for example).  Since the fields are part of your page when it loads, they will have IDs and you can do whatever you want with their data.

Jquery Dialog documentation: http://jqueryui.com/dialog/